# Click and Drag to Multiselect Checkboxes in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, checkbox

**The problem:**

My application requires a user to be able to select multiple entries in a datagrid via a column of checkboxes. The desired behavior is that when you click on a checkbox in the column, it behaves like a normal checkbox, but if you drag over it while the left mouse button is down, its selection state changes to the opposite of what is was before.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have tried subclassing CheckBox and handling OnMouseEnter, but the first checkbox that is clicked seems to capture the mouse so no other checkboxes fire the OnMouseEnter event.

I have tried implementing a drag-and-drop hack, where the user clicks to select a checkbox, and then drags that checkbox over the others so the others recieve a DragOver event and can switch states. This solution causes the cursor to display as a circle with a slash when not over another checkbox during the drag and drop, which is not acceptable for this application.

**What I would like:**

I would like a method to implement a checkbox that has the functionality I describe, ideally in a xaml style or subclass that I can reuse, as this functionality is needed in multiple places in my application.

**Is there an elegant way to achieve this effect?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this in my application, very handy when you have to select, say, 30 checkBoxes.
To do this, i handled the preview mouse event myself : PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, PreviewMouseMove, PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp.

In PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown : i get the mouse position relative to the control.
In PreviewMouseMove : i draw a rectangle from start to current position if i am far enough from firstPoint. then i iterate in CheckBoxes, see if they intersect with rectangle, and highlight them if so (so the user know whiwh chexboxes will swap)
In PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp : i do the swap for intersecting CheckBoxes.

if it can help you, here's the code i use. it is not MVVM (:-)) but works fine, it might give you ideas.  it is an automatic translation from vb.net code.

To make it work, you need a Canvas on top of your CheckBoxes (=within the same grid cell for instance), with property IsHitTestVisible="False" .
Within this Canvas, put a Rectangle nammed "SelectionRectangle" with proper fill and stroke, but with 0.0 Opacity.

```
// '' <summary>
// '' When Left Mouse button is pressed, remember where the mouse move start
// '' </summary>
private void EditedItems_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    StartPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
}

// '' <summary>
// '' When mouse move, update the highlight of the selected items.
// '' </summary>
private void EditedItems_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e) {
    if ((StartPoint == null)) {
        return;
    }
    PointWhereMouseIs = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    Rect SelectedRect = new Rect(StartPoint, PointWhereMouseIs);
    if (((SelectedRect.Width < 20) 
                && (SelectedRect.Height < 20))) {
        return;
    }
    //  show the rectangle again
    Canvas.SetLeft(SelectionRectangle, Math.Min(StartPoint.X, PointWhereMouseIs.X));
    Canvas.SetTop(SelectionRectangle, Math.Min(StartPoint.Y, PointWhereMouseIs.Y));
    SelectionRectangle.Width = Math.Abs((PointWhereMouseIs.X - StartPoint.X));
    SelectionRectangle.Height = Math.Abs((PointWhereMouseIs.Y - StartPoint.Y));
    foreach (CheckBox ThisChkBox in EditedItems.Children) {
        object rectBounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(ThisChkBox);
        Vector vector = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(ThisChkBox);
        rectBounds.Offset(vector);
        if (rectBounds.IntersectsWith(SelectedRect)) {
            ((TextBlock)(ThisChkBox.Content)).Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
        }
        else {
            ((TextBlock)(ThisChkBox.Content)).Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
    }
}

// '' <summary>
// '' When Left Mouse button is released, change all CheckBoxes values. (Or do nothing if it is a small move -->
// '' click will be handled in a standard way.)
// '' </summary>
private void EditedItems_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    PointWhereMouseIs = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    Rect SelectedRect = new Rect(StartPoint, PointWhereMouseIs);
    StartPoint = null;
    SelectionRectangle.Opacity = 0;
    //  hide the rectangle again
    if (((SelectedRect.Width < 20) 
                && (SelectedRect.Height < 20))) {
        return;
    }
    foreach (CheckBox ThisEditedItem in EditedItems.Children) {
        object rectBounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(ThisEditedItem);
        Vector vector = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(ThisEditedItem);
        rectBounds.Offset(vector);
        if (rectBounds.IntersectsWith(SelectedRect)) {
            ThisEditedItem.IsChecked = !ThisEditedItem.IsChecked;
        }
        ((TextBlock)(ThisEditedItem.Content)).Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    }
}
```

Edit : i used that code within a user control. This control takes a list of booleans and a list of strings (caption) as argument, and builds (with a WrapPanel) an array of CheckBoxes having the right caption. And so you can select/unselect with the rectangle, and there are also two buttons  to check all/uncheck all. I tried also to keep good column/rows ratio to handle selection of 7 to 200 booleans with a good column/row balance.

[image: An exemple of use of the BooleanEdit User Control within a Window]

Comment: Thanks for your help. While this isn't the elegant solution I was looking for, it's better than anything I managed to come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is a few months old but I think I have the elegant answer you are looking for.

Since you describe dragging and checking as two separate behaviors, first set your datagrid MouseDown handler...

```
yourdatagrid.MouseDown += DragCheck_MouseDownHandler;
```

This will allow a drag start from the datagrid background (but not a control in the grid.)

```
    private void DragCheck_MouseDownHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
        Control dgrid = sender as Control;
        foreach (CheckBox box in dgrid.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            box.Tag = null;
        }
        dgrid.MouseMove += DragMove_MouseMoveHandler;
    }
```

This uses the `checkbox.Tag` as a toggle for one pass only dragging while the mouse is down.  If you use the CheckBox tags for something else I am sure you can find your own way to identify the boxes.  The `datagrid.MouseMove` is set for the next handler....

```
    private void DragMove_MouseMoveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control dgrid = sender as Control;

        Point now = dgrid.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Control under = dgrid.GetChildAtPoint(now);
            if (under != null && under.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                //if the point has a valid CheckBox control under it
                CheckBox box = under as CheckBox;
                if (box.Tag == null)// not yet been swiped
                {
                    box.Checked = !box.Checked;
                    box.Tag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if MouseButtons no longer registers as left
            //remove the handler 

            dgrid.MouseMove -= DragMove_MouseMoveHandler;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drag to Select Checkboxes</title>
    <style>
        .checkbox-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .checkbox {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            margin: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .number {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="checkboxContainer" class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox-item">
            <div class="number">1</div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-item">
            <div class="number">2</div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-item">
            <div class="number">3</div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
        </div>
        <!-- Add more checkbox items here as needed -->
    </div>
    <script>
        let isDragging = false;
        let selectedCheckboxes = [];

        const checkboxItems = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-item');

        checkboxItems.forEach(checkboxItem => {
            const checkbox = checkboxItem.querySelector('.checkbox');
            const number = checkboxItem.querySelector('.number');

            number.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
                isDragging = true;
                selectedCheckboxes.push(checkbox);
                checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
            });

            number.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
                isDragging = false;
            });

            number.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                if (isDragging) {
                    selectedCheckboxes.push(checkbox);
                    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
                }
            });
        });

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            isDragging = false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Running this code snippet doesn't seem to produce the result the OP is asking for.

Comment: The OP's quesiton is about XAML, not HTML